# Concat Publishers with Reractor but process elements different

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<Integer> lower = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Flux<Integer> upper = Flux.just(6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    Flux<Integer> total = Flux.concat(lower, upper);
    total.subscribe(n -> System.out.println(n * 1));
}
```

is it possible to multiply lower elements by 1 and upper elements by 2? In the real world i could not distinguish by which publisher an element was produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use the `map()` operator on both:

```
Flux<Integer> lower = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(i -> i * 1); // completely unnecessary, but you asked for it
Flux<Integer> upper = Flux.just(6, 7, 8, 9, 10).map(i -> i * 2);
Flux<Integer> total = Flux.concat(lower, upper);
total.subscribe(n -> System.out.println(n));
```